# add element with add_action to posts from a specific category ID

Tags: php, actions

I just try to add some content at the bottom of each posts from a specific category but the content is added in all posts. I use a hook in GeneratePress theme. I don't understand why it is not working. I'm not a pro with PHP to be honest (maybe it's obvious ). Thanks

```
function bottom_post_message() {
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '3,5' ) );
    if(is_single() && is_category($query)) {
        echo '<p>Hello World!</p>';
    }
}
add_action( 'generate_after_entry_content', 'bottom_post_message' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just try to add some content at the bottom of each posts from a
> specific category but the content is added in all posts.

Are you sure your "Hello World!" text is added in all posts? Because `is_single() && is_category()` would never be true because a query can't be for a single *post* and a category archive at the same time.

So if you want to check if the current (or a specific) post is within a specific category, you would instead use [`in_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/in_category/) like so:

```php
function bottom_post_message() {
    // Check if the current request/URL is for a single post, and that the post is
    // in any of the categories passed to in_category().
    if ( is_single() && in_category( array( 3, 5 ) ) ) {
        // your code
    }
}
```

And note that you incorrectly used `is_category()` — you should pass the category IDs and not an instance of `WP_Query`.

See the documentation for [`is_single()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/) and [`is_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_category/) for more details about the functions (what they do, correct syntax, etc.).

Comment: Hi Sally and thanks for your answer. Sorry I'v made so many try and so I pasted the wrong code (my bad). With the last one I used, I wasn't using $query, but you really helped me with in_category() which I didn't know. For some reason it works fine with the category slug (array('blog', 'blog-fr')) but not with ID, but is doesn't really matter. Thanks a lot for putting me on the right path.

Comment: Are you sure you used the correct IDs? Try checking in wp-admin. You should also know that you need to supply actual *integers* if you're passing category IDs to `in_category()`, e.g. use `in_category( 3 )` and *not* `in_category( '3' )`.

Comment: Damn, I really lack of focusing! I removed the '' and it works just fine now. Thanks again for you precious help.